# Julia performance advices

Tags: c++, performance, julia

I wrote a really simple program in order to compare performance from Julia vs C / C++.  Basically it returns the total prime numbers less than a given number.  The problem is that I got an average time 2.5x worse than c/c++ equivalent (AFAIK, it should be somewhat near to 1.0x).  I’m using Julia 0.5.0 (but, I also tested on 0.6.0, getting the same result).  I found out that changing `%` for `mod` to do the modulus operation helped.  Also, setting types everywhere give me some gain.

Can someone help me figure out what else I’m missing to improve Julia’s performance in this example?  Thanks in advance.

```
    module modIsPrime
    export isprime, Test_isprime

    @inline function isprime( nNumber :: Int64 ) :: Int64
      s = Int( trunc( sqrt( nNumber ) ) )
      if mod( nNumber, 2 ) == 0
        return 0
      else
        for i = 3 : 2 : s
          if mod( nNumber, i ) == 0
            return 0
          end
        end
        return 1
      end
    end

    function Test_isprime( )
      nPrimeNumbers :: Int64 = 0
      n             :: Int64 = 0
      for n = 1 : 2 : 16000000
        nPrimeNumbers += isprime( n )
      end
      display( [ "Prime numbers: " nPrimeNumbers ] )
    end
    end
```

Edit - As Ron mentioned, here is the C++ code I used to do the comparison:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <chrono>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <omp.h>
    #include <math.h>
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    #define DEFAULT_MAX_TESTS 16'000'000

    inline int isprime( unsigned long nNumber ) {
      unsigned long
        i
      , s = static_cast< unsigned long >( sqrt( static_cast< double >( nNumber ) ) )
      ;
      if ( nNumber % 2 == 0 ) {
        return 0;
      } else {
        for( i = 3; i <= s; i += 2 ) {
          if ( nNumber % i == 0 ) return 0;
        } // for.
        return 1;
      } // else.
    } // isprime.

    int main( ) {
      const unsigned long cstnMaxTests  = DEFAULT_MAX_TESTS;
            unsigned long nPrimeNumbers = 0;
      steady_clock::time_point start = steady_clock::now( );
      for( long n = 1; n < cstnMaxTests; n += 2 ) {
        nPrimeNumbers += isprime( n );
      } // for.
      steady_clock::time_point end = steady_clock::now( );
      auto time = duration_cast< milliseconds >( end - start ).count( );
      cout
              << "milliseconds: "     << time
      << endl << "Number of Primes: " << nPrimeNumbers
      << endl
      ;
      return 0;
    } // main.
```

Comment: Unless you make a direct comparison to a specific C program (which you should show) or a specific C++ program (which you should show) then this is a Julia-specific question and should only have that language tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here some the code that works around 4 times faster than yours:

```
module modIsPrime

export isprime, Test_isprime

@inline function isprime(nNumber)
    nNumber & 1 == 0 && return 0
    for i = 3:2:isqrt(nNumber)
        i*unsafe_trunc(Int,nNumber/i) == nNumber && return 0
    end
    return 1
end

function Test_isprime()
    nPrimeNumbers = 1
    for n = 3:2:16000000
        nPrimeNumbers += isprime(n)
    end
    println("Prime numbers: ", nPrimeNumbers)
end

end
```

It would be nice to be able to see the comparisons of timings on the same machine (I do not have C++ compiler at hand). There is a small fix in `Test_isprime` for correct counting (the result is the same, but you counted `1` as prime and `2` as composite in your code).

**EDIT**: I have moved calculation of `isqrt` after testing is number is even which saves some time (not a major thing though), if you want a fair comparison to C++ it should be moved there also.

Comment: In my experience `isqrt` is very slow. Maybe use `floor(Int, sqrt(nNumber))` instead?

Comment: Yes - this is faster, but it is not always correct. I have used a safe option as `isqrt` is not a performance critical part of the code. Actually C++ code seems to have the problem with precision also (so for performance testing we could switch to your approach). To see why `isqrt` is needed check both methods e.g. for the number `3^36-1`.

Comment: @Bogumił-Kamiński, you are right.  To be fair, I moved the sqrt calculation to an equivalent point at the c++ code, but the result was almost the same.  I guess, c++ already made this optimization for me!  Your code was faster, and now I got a 1.6x ratio which I consider pretty good.  Also I realize that fixing types for Julia seems to be pointless.  It was a surprise to realize that `i*unsafe_trunc(Int,nNumber/i) == nNumber` would be faster than a traditional `mod`.  Thank you very much.

Comment: "It was a surprise to realize that i*unsafe_trunc(Int,nNumber/i) == nNumber would be faster than a traditional mod" `mod` is just a slow operation in modern processors and should be avoided when you can. That's not just a Julia thing.

Comment: Additionally, note that the solution works only for integers that fit into `Float64` with full precision (so we have a similar problem here as with running `floor` on `sqrt(nNumber)`).